# typeError: fs/promises read is not a function

Tags: node.js, file-descriptor

I am trying to use the `fs/promises`  module.  Node version is v14.17.0

The code below throws an error: `TypeError: read is not a function`

```js
(async () => {
    'use strict';
    const { open, read } = require('fs/promises');
    const fd = await open('/proc/loadavg', 'r');
    const { bytesRead, buffer } = await read(fd, Buffer.alloc(1024));
    console.log({ bytesRead, data: buffer.toString() });
})()
    .catch(console.error);
```

When I try it with the non promise version it works.

```js
'use strict';

const { open, read } = require('fs');
const { exit } = require('process');

open('/proc/loadavg', 'r', (err, fd) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        exit(2);
    }
    read(fd, Buffer.alloc(1024), 0, 1024, 0, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            exit(2);
        }
        console.log({ bytesRead, data: buffer.toString() });
    });
});
```

Why is the first one not working?

Edit: Here is what vscode is showing me. According to one comment this isn't true.

[image]

I found the type in `fs.d.ts`

```
function read<TBuffer extends Uint8Array>(
            handle: FileHandle,
            buffer: TBuffer,
            offset?: number | null,
            length?: number | null,
            position?: number | null,
        ): Promise<{ bytesRead: number, buffer: TBuffer }>;
```

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? Before 14 you had to use `require('fs').promises`.

Comment: Actually that probably doesn't matter, because looking at https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html there isn't a promisified version of read.

Comment: Ah vscode intellisense is auto completing it for me as if it would exsit. Nice.

Comment: check my update I have added a screenshot @jonrsharpe. I guess I can promisify it myself in that case. Still weird of VS Code to do that.

Comment: Reading in the promise interface is done via `fileHandle.read()`, not via `fs.promises.read()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading in the promise interface is done via `fileHandle.read()`, not via `fs.promises.read()`.

You could manually promisify `fs.read()` and `fs.open()` yourself, but the intention of the promise interface is to direct people to use the fileHandle interface instead which has some advantages.

Also, this code:

```
const fd = await open('/proc/loadavg', 'r');
```

doesn't return an `fd`.  It returns a fileHandle object (which you then do `.read()` on, so you'll have to change the `.read()` code and the `.close()` code for that anyway.

Comment: ok thank you. Any Idea why its reading zero bytes now? `const { bytesRead, buffer } = await fd.read(Buffer.alloc(1024));`

Comment: Where could one get info on the "some advantages"?

Comment: @TheFool - The "some advantages" has more to do with now having an cleaner object oriented interface and a live Javascript object for an open file which makes the interface on an open file more encapsulated and gives you an object to keep track of file state on, to subclass, etc...  I think there are things being worked on related to warning when a file is left open, but it's handle object has been garbage collected as that would represent a filehandle leak.

Comment: Well, I am reading now here in this page. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_read_options. But I still don't  really understand why its reading zero bytes.  I also thought that the file descriptor is closed when the program exists.

Comment: @TheFool - I'd have to see the exact code you're running to get an idea why it's reading zero bytes.  File descriptors are closed by the OS when the process exits, but in a long running process (like a server), if you regularly open files and don't close them, then you start eating up available file descriptors and can eventually run out.  It is definitely a good practice to close any file handle when you're done with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the adivse on `close`. Thats the code, I just changed that one line. ![zero byte code](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39703898/119624730-5974be80-be01-11eb-916c-625dad5cde1b.png)

Comment: @TheFool - If you pass the `offset` and `length` arguments to `fh.read()`, it works for me.  The doc indicates those will take on default values, but that doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Oh, yes right. I think because proc files don't really have a length. You also couldn't do a seek on it. So maybe that's why in this case you need to tell the length.